# How to call csImageFile.dll (com) functions in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, vbscript

I want to convert a classic asp / VB script code section to c#. The code uses a dll **csImageFile.dll** that specifically merge multiple tif images

Legacy function

```
nPage = 1
Set csImg = Server.CreateObject("csImageFile.Manage")
    do while not rs.eof
        csImg.ReadStream "tif", rs("imagedata").value
        csImg.AddToTif nPage
        nPage = nPage + 1
        rs.movenext
    loop
rs.close
```

Till now i have managed to create an instance of the dll file (in c#) as below

```
Type aType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("csImageFile.Manage", true);
Object anObject = Activator.CreateInstance(aType);
```

i am confused in how can in call the function from the following legacy code

```
csImg.ReadStream "tif", rs("imagedata").value
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be easier to create a runtime callable wrapper (RCW) .NET assembly

```
tlbimp csImageFile.dll /out:Interop.csImageFile.dll /namespace:csImageFile
```

And then use the COM classes exposed by it as if they were regular .NET ones:

```
csImageFile.Manage csImg = new csImageFile.Manage();
csImg.ReadStream("tif", rs("imagedata").value);
```

But don't forget to include a reference to Interop.csImageFile.dll  into your project.